# Generating preview images of style x fabric x color

Tags: image-preview

I am looking into rendering preview images of products (furniture) automatically. For a furniture webshop it is impossible to manually take pictures of all possible combinations of style, fabric and color. The main products sold will be sofas in different styles with different options of fabric and color.

Is it somehow possible to create those images based on some base images of the product and an image of the fabric? Or any other ideas of how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would suggest uploading a couple of pictures of the sofa for example from different corners and for different fabrics sample photo's so the user can see color and texture from up close.

Rendering a compilation of shape, fabric and color would require in my opinion a pretty advanced Flash application (or something along that line) to make it even remotely realistic.

Comment: Thanks Sander and agreed. It doesn't specifically have to be rendered live. It can be a tool that I run once and generate all images I need. I looked at KeyShot which allows you to render very realistic images, but it's all manual work. I can see that it would require quite some AI and it's probably too much of a stretch at this point.